# Почему не проходит post запрос ( express + gulp + jquery )?!

Tags: node.js, post

В общем пол дня просидел и проблему не решил! 
Форма создается динамически

**public/js/main.js**

```
    var answerOrQuestion = '';
    answerOrQuestion += '<form method="post" action="" id="answerOrQuestionContainer"><div class="rasporka"></div><hr>';
    answerOrQuestion += '<p><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" /></p>';
    answerOrQuestion += '<p><textarea name="answer"  placeholder="Your answer"></textarea></p>';
    answerOrQuestion += '<input type="submit" value="Post Your Answer" />';
    answerOrQuestion += '</form>';

    $('.container').append(answerOrQuestion);
```

Обработка формы:

```
        $('.container').on("submit", '#answerOrQuestionContainer', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            $.post("/question/saveQuestion", function (result) {});

        });
```

**app.js**

```
var question = require('./routes/question');

app.get('/question', question);
```

**routes/question.js**

```
router.post('/saveQuestion', function(req, res) {
/* что-то делаем */
});
```

И получаем 404 при попытке отправить запрос!
У кого-то есть какие-либо предположения?! Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С формой всё в порядке, запрос ведь отправляется.
То, что страница не найдена, говорит о том, что что-то неладно на сервере. И действительно, вы неправильно инициализируете роутер. Должно быть так: `app.use('/question', question);`
[Документация](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html#express-router).

Comment: спасибо друг!) сам не знаю как так лоханулся!)) пол дня, реально пол дня))))))